# General form of iterates $f^{n}(x)$ for $f(x) = \frac{x}{1-x}$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, induction

> *Let $f: \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $f(x)  =  \frac{x}{1-x}$.  Define  $f^{2}(x)  =  f(f(x))$,  $f^{3}(x)  =  f(f(f(x)))$, ...
>
>   Guess the form  for $f^{n}(x)$ and prove  your answer is correct using induction on n.*

My Approach:

$f^{n}(x)$ = $\frac{x}{1 - nx}$ since $f^{2}(x)$ = $\frac{x}{1-x}$ $/$ $1$ - $\frac{x}
{1-x}$

= $\frac{x}{1 - 2x}$ = $\frac{x}{1 - nx}$     (Since 2 = n so it must be n * x)

Proof By Induction:

Denote $f^{n}(x)$ = $\frac{x}{1 - nx}$

Base Case:

When $n$ = $1$

$f^{1}(x)$ = $\frac{x}{1-(1)*(x)}$ = $\frac{x}{1 - x}$ = $f(x)$

which is true since $f^{1}(x)$ = $f(x)$

I.H:

$f^{k}(x)$ = $\frac{x}{1 - kx}$ where $n$ = $k$ for any arbitrary $k > 0$ this holds true because of the base case

I.S:

$f^{k+1}(x)$ = $f(f^{k}(x))$

= $f$($\frac{x}{1 - kx}$$)$

= $f$($\frac{x}{(1 - x)k+1}$$)$

= $f$($\frac{1}{(1)(k+1)}$$)$  (Canceling $x$ out)

= $f$($\frac{k+1}{1}$$)$    (Reciprocal of $\frac{1}{k + 1}$ is $\frac{k + 1}{1}$)

= $f$($k + 1$)

Any help or hints would be appreciated

Comment: Before you try induction, manually compute what $f^2(x)$,$f^3(x)$,$f^4(x)$ is, etc., until you see a pattern.  For the first, plug f(x) into the x in each place, and evaluate.

Comment: Thanks, check out my post now I changed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's compute $f^2(x)$ to guess the form of the general expression:

$$f^{\color{red}2}(x)=\frac{\frac x{1-x}}{1-\frac x{1-x}}=\frac x{1-\color{red}2x}$$
Now can you prove by induction that

$$f^{\color{red}n}(x)=\frac x{1-\color{red}nx}$$

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense, didn't think of it that way

Comment: I edited the post, check if it makes sense now thanks.

Comment: To check the inductive step note that
$$f^{k+1}(x)=f(f^k(x))$$
and replace $f^k(x)$ by the expression of the I.H.

Comment: Thanks Sami for the useful hints, i just edited my I.S

Comment: I have a question, after i simplify it i get f(k-1) instead of f(k+1)

Comment: You made a mistake in your answer: you can't cancel by $x$ by the manner what you did.

Comment: Ok I edited it, if you have time check it out

Comment: This is the answer:
$$f^{k+1}(x)=f(f^{k}(x))=\frac{f^{k}(x)}{1-f^{k}(x)}=\frac{\frac{x}{1-kx}}{1-\frac{x}{1-kx}}=\frac{x}{1-(k+1)x}$$
and we get the inductive step.